# Get the span class name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape a website. The retrieved resultset looks like this:

```
<td><span class="I_Want_This_Class_Name"></span><span class="other_name">Text Is Here</span></td>
```

From here, I want to retrieve the class name "I_Want_This_Class_Name". I can get the "Text Is Here" part no problem, but the class name itself is proving to be difficult.

Is there a way to do this using BeautifulSoup resultset or do I need to convert to a dictionary?

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code generating the shown output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''<td><span class="I_Want_This_Class_Name"></span><span class="other_name">Text Is Here</span></td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

res = soup.find('td')
out = {}
for each in res:
  if each.has_attr('class'):
    out[each['class'][0]] = each.text
print(out)
```

output will be like:

{'I_Want_This_Class_Name': '', 'other_name': 'Text Is Here'}

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the class name for this one result, then I would use the select method on your soup object, calling the class key:

```
foo_class = soup.select('td>span.I_Want_This_Class_Name')[0]['class'][0]
```

Note here that the select method does return a list, hence the indexing before the key.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a list of results. So the class names change for each and I don't know them beforehand